# React component with image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a sample React app. I've put my components in separate folders - one folder for each major component.

```
app/
  components/
    shared/
    appcard/
      images/
      appcard.js
      reviews.js
  index.js
  index.html
dist
```

I was thinking to store images used in the component in the images subfolder (Appcard/images). The idea would be to have a self contained component in that folder, with all the styles, images and whatever else it needs. That way, if I would copy it to another app (with another structure), I wouldn't have to change anything in the component code (or copy images from other folders,etc)

I'm using Webpack for the build.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Or it's a bad idea(better done another way,etc)?

Comment: It would help if you include some more details about the folder structure and your build system (you mention `./Appcard/images` but then use `./img` in the image src which implies the build is moving files around). As you're probably aware, the relative path for resources is relative to the root folder from which your app is hosted, not from the individual JS files.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add an edit to be more clear

Comment: This question depends on how you are building your images into your project. I see you are using react. Are use using webpack to build?

http://webpack.github.io/

Comment: yeap. I'm building with webpack. I think I need a way to copy my images directory from the component folder to the build(dist) folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can just move your images folder outside of app. This way you won't need to concern yourself with copying the folder between build and dist.